# What is the joint distribution between the sample mean and sample mediant of rounded normal variables?

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, estimators, bivariate

I am curious about the relationship between the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) and the [(generalized) mediant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)#Generalization). I took $10^4$ samples (each of size $n=3$) of $\operatorname{Round}(X_i,\text{decimals}=3)$ where $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and are independent. For each sample I computed the arithmetic mean and the (generalized) mediant, with all weights equal to unity, and plotted their scatter.

For computing the mediant I chose to put the rounded variables into a [reduced fraction](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReducedFraction.html). For example, if $\operatorname{round}(\pi, 3) = 3.142$ then this was rewritten as $\frac{1571}{500}$. If a value was negative, the negative sign went to the numerator.

[image]

The scatter suggests a normal-like joint distribution for the sample mean and mediant.

The shape of this joint distribution doesn't seem to vary much by sample size:

| n=10 | n=100 | n=1000 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

But changing the population mean does seem to increase the intercept of a simple linear model (at n=3). Specifically, it seems to increase the intercept by approximately an order of magnitude.

| mu=10 | mu=100 | mu=1000 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

I also found that increasing the population standard deviations, leaving the mean at zero, had more sampling variability in the regression coefficients but didn't seem to change the typical value (not shown).

And here are QQ-plots looking at the normality of the sampled means and mediants at n=3. The red lines are the 45 degree line through the origin. They both agree with normality. I've thrown some histograms with best-fitting normal distributions, and they look quite normal-like.

| means | mediants |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |

Can it be confirmed analytically that the sample mean and sample mediant approximately have a joint normal distribution?

Comment: Please tell us what the "generalized mediant" of a *distribution* might be.  It is difficult, if not impossible, to apply the concept in the link to any continuous distribution.

Comment: Rounding to three decimal places is a change of variables that obtains a discrete random variable.

Comment: I missed the reference in the code.  Regardless, this looks incredibly artificial: could you explain what statistical application it might have?  It's also unclear what you might mean by "simplified fractional form."  Do you mean you reduced the fractions to make their numerator and denominator relatively prime?

Comment: Yes, "simplified fractional form" was a non-standard terminology for "reduced fraction". Updated.

Comment: Thank you.  I still don't understand your question, because obviously the sample mean and mediant can attain only a limited number of possible values: for instance, the sample mean must be a multiple of $1/3000.$  Such a distribution, which is manifestly discrete, cannot be Normal.

Comment: Good point. I've refined to asking if an approximation can be shown. Perhaps there is a better refinement than "approximation", but my first guess is CLT or similar could apply here given the visualizations show good agreement with the predicted normal quantiles.